# Design pattern for similar processing steps, but with slight variations

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What is a good design pattern to implement a feature, where processing of data is pretty similar, except for variations in may be few steps... I initially thought that Chain-Of-Responsibility may be suitable... but it doesn't feel like the right choice.. If I'd know the name of appropriate pattern, I'd search it on internet.. but I don't know what pattern to use here.. So please suggest one.

To be clear with an example -

Scenario 1
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4

Scenario 2
Step 1
Step A
Step 3
Step 4

Would like to implement the feature in such a way that minimum code duplication is necessary.

I do realize that something will have to chain the necessary steps together at the start, like a factory, based on the scenario.

Comment: One of the things that the [link] (http://amzn.com/0321889061)'Emergent Design' uses to compare design patterns what do you want/need to encapsulate.

Comment: What I want to encapsulate is the fact that few steps of the whole process could be vary, based on some criteria known at the start of the processing... I don't want to put if/else statements in the step(s) in between, and I do not want one step to call the next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described may be solved by pipelining, where a set of steps are linked together to pass data through a "pipeline".  There are different means of accomplishing this in different languages, but here is an example with data flow pipelining in .NET (C#): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx and an alternative in Java using Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-pipeline/pipeline_basics.html

Comment: Sounds good.. Thanks for the response.. +1, but will wait for more responses to compare against other suggestions.. Although I do think pipeline is a way to look at it.. the article seems very specific to parallel processing.. Do you have other references on the subject?

Comment: not that I do not have multiple inputs to process.. which is what pipeline pattern seems to be appropriate for.. I have to process only one item, but one of the steps in processing may vary based on type of item.

Comment: The MSDN link gets into parallel processing since each pipeline stage can be processed without side effects, making it something that can be performed in parallel.  Maybe the Apache Commons Pipeline explains the concept without getting into parallelism (at least right away).  Basically you have a number of stages for processing data, each defined in a "Stage" class with a "process()" method.  These stages are assembled into a Queue, and the pipeline would pop each stage off the queue and pass the data to it, passing the result on to the next stage until you reach the end of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

From your example it seems to me that [Template pattern](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Template_method_pattern) would be more appropriate when sequence/steps are always the same but one or more steps has different implementations.
In case number of steps variate much more, for example completely different step order, sometimes just few steps sometimes some steps are skipped than [Strategy pattern](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Strategy_pattern) would be better solution.

However if you need to apply different rules after another (like graphics filters) on a object than pipeline would be more appropriate. As soon as one "filter" finishes you give the object to the next one in the pipeline